# What is the alternative to using --process-dependency-links with pip

Tags: git, version-control, pip, setuptools, easy-install

I am using Python 2.7. I am trying to `pip install` a repo (on internal github) that has a dependency on another repo (also on internal github). I tried several options but the one that worked was like this:

```
(env)abc$ cat requirements.txt
 -e git://github.abc.com/abc/abc.git#egg=my_abc --process-dependency-links

(env)abc$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I got a warning while running the command line  that said:

*"DEPRECATION: Dependency Links processing has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release."*

I am on pip v7.1.2. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is [an alternative](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4187)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PEP 508 URL requirements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#examples):

```
pip @ https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/19.2.3.zip
```

They'll work for direct requirements (via the CLI, or listed in `requirements.txt`) and packages that aren't downloaded by pip from PyPI. Note that support for this was released in pip 18.0 (i.e. early 2018, because pip's on CalVer now).

---

In OP's case, the `requirements.txt` can be unchanged (though, they'd want to remove `--process-dependency-links`), if the dependency links are updated to the PEP 508 format.

Comment: Updated my answer, to reflect the current state of affairs.

Answer (score -1):

Try using   `--process-dependency-links` flag option. You might also have to use `--allow-external packagename` 
 or `--allow-unverified packagename`, where packagename actually specifies whichever dependency 
 you want to install that's not in an official repository

Note:Since it's deprecated functionality, the `--process-dependency-links` 
flag will be completely removed soon.
I believe the preferred approach is to supply a `requirements.txt` file instead.
For Example : Let i have certain requirements for my project, so i will write that in requirements.txt.

```
&cat requirements.txt

django-compressor>=1.4,<1.5
django-grappelli>=2.6.3,<2.7
django-bootstrap-form>=3.1,<3.2
```

Next i can install it using :

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

That's all you have to do

Comment: Please see the edit above. I am already using requirements.txt with the contents shown in my original posting. What else do I need?

Comment: requirement.txt should contain all the dependent requirement , --process-dependency-links shouldn't be there , instead it should contain list of all dependent requirements .

Comment: i guess you may wish to accept it as an answer too. if it solved your purpose

Comment: @csharpcoder The stated preferred approach doesn't work because `pip` doesn't parse the requirements file recursively! In effect, the requirements of a requirement are not installed!